# What is best way to secure t-sql dynamic code when it comes as filters using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

I'm making a stored procedure which accepts dynamic filtering, the problem I have is that I need to keep it flexible as possible.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE astp_test
    @WhereClause NVARCHAR(max) = NULL
AS

DECLARE @FilteredResults AS TABLE (testId int, testfield datetime2)
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT testId ,                               testfield 
                                        FROM aviw_test
                                        WHERE IsOpen = 1 AND IsLatesInsert = 1
                                            AND testStepNo = 7
                                            AND test2 IS NULL
                                            AND (testfielddate IS NULL OR testfielddate2 < GETUTCDATE()) 
                                            AND Domain IN (SELECT Domain FROM project WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Status = ''Active'')' + 
    CASE WHEN @WhereClause IS NOT NULL 
        THEN  N' AND ' + @WhereClause ELSE N''
    END

INSERT INTO @FilteredResults
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql;
```

I want to secure `@WhereClause` input but in this way, because there are some check boxes which send something like this : `"AND testDatePick = '2019-10-10' AND testStage = 'InProgress' AND testArea = 'London' "`. So what would be the best way to do it ?

Comment: The best way is to *not* use dynamic sql. What does `@WhereClause` contain? Why not use an ORM to generate a good SQL query? In fact, why not convert that `@sql` into a view and write a simple query on it? PS `WITH (NOLOCK)` won't make a slow query run faster, it will read dirty data while taking *extra locks*. To make this subquery run faster, add an index on `Status, Domain` and possibly use SNAPSHOT isolation

Comment: I disagree with that, @PanagiotisKanavos . The best way, however, is the **safely** inject object names (using `QUOTENAME`) and to parametrise the statement. Injecting a `WHERE` is completely the wrong idea though, as you'll never be able to make that safe.

Comment: @Larnu that `@sql` should be a view, not part of a dynamic query to begin with.

Comment: If you're going to accept raw SQL there's no good way to protect against anything; you'll have to trust the client as parsing T-SQL in T-SQL is a non-starter. In that case, it would be much better to centralize the query logic in the client altogether so you have one place to verify it, and declare a view for the parts of the query that won't change. I also recommend reading [this article](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for lots of background information on different, safer ways to do dynamic search (and the pitfalls associated with each approach).

Comment: Personally, I don't like using dynamic SQL for this kind of things. Most of the times, I rather use the catch-all pattern [described here](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).

Comment: BTW, `sp_executeSql` doesn't make this query even slightly more secure. In this case, there's no difference between that and simply `exec(@sql)`.

Comment: I was disagreeing with the sweeping statement *"The best way is to **not** use dynamic sql."* @PanagiotisKanavos . The comment had been editted since to expand, but certainly saying just saying "dynamic SQL is bad" is wrong. Poorly written Dynamic SQL is bad, but well written, secure dynamic SQL is fine; and there are certainly times for its uses.

Comment: I know that this is not a good way, but this is not my code, I just need to improve it to be more safer, but have no ideas, because @WhereClause from web allready comes as 'DateTest = '2019-01-10'' and so on, so i can't make them as parameters.So looking for best solution to improve it.

Comment: The best solution to improve it would be to change the implementation.

Comment: So I could make that not sp_executesql but rather to collect all data from view, but the problem is thar i cant' use it like this: Select * FROM test WHERE IsOpen = 1 AND @WhereClause

Comment: To "fix" (secure) it, @pixe you need to remove that parameter `@WhereClause` and replace it with 1 parameter per column that needs to be compared. That **will** require both a change at the Database *and* the application. That is a **requirement**. There is no way you can make it secure without doing so. If you can't do that, I **strongly** suggest you remove the functionality.

Comment: T-SQL has nothing in the way of parsing, expression trees, or anything else that would allow a secure implementation of `AND @WhereClause`. It's either blindly trusting what's in `@WhereClause`, or not accepting raw SQL in strings, with the latter obviously being preferable to the former. In theory, you could have a CLR function that does T-SQL parsing (by using the `TSqlParser` classes) and verify that your raw SQL contains only what you expect of it, but this would be a massively overengineered solution with alternatives that are far easier to trust.

Comment: Well, this statement is quite concerning: "because @WhereClause from web allready comes as 'DateTest = '2019-01-10'' and so on,". To secure dynamic SQL, one must use parameters queries. That implies the stored proc interface needs to be changed to accommodate parameters needed for the `WHERE` clause and the web pass those values in native types instead of passing an arbitrary T-SQL string. [This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) may help.

Comment: What about converting it as nvarchar? CAST(@WhereClause AS NVARCHAR(300) ) ?? Would it implement it as string and no special chars will escape query ? ?

Comment: No. Please take everyone's comments seriously when we say there is no safe solution if raw SQL is passed in from the clients, if you cannot fully trust the clients. While it is possible to escape the string in such a way that the value itself can be safely handled  (`QUOTENAME(mystring, ''''`) this will simply give you the SQL as a string literal, which is of no use for actually executing it as part of the query.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE astp_test
        @WhereClause NVARCHAR(max) = NULL
    AS

    DECLARE @FilteredResults AS TABLE (testId int, testfield datetime2)
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT testId ,                               testfield 
                                            FROM aviw_test
                                            WHERE IsOpen = 1 AND IsLatesInsert = 1
                                                AND testStepNo = 7
                                                AND test2 IS NULL
                                                AND (testfielddate IS NULL OR testfielddate2 < GETUTCDATE()) 
                                                AND Domain IN (SELECT Domain FROM project WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Status = ''Active'')' 

if @WhereClause is not null
set @sql=@sql + 'AND ' + @WhereClause

    INSERT INTO @FilteredResults
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql;
```

Please let me know if you have any issue

Thanks